# LSTM model for multiclass classification accuracy

Tags: lstm, sequential

I have an LSTM model that makes prediction for a multi class problem. The data consists of customer order history. Each row contains previous 3 sequentail orders of a specific event cumulatively. There are also multiple features for each of the sequences of a row.

The input data has customers cumulative order values with 3 labels. t-1 and t-2 have previous values for n days earlier.

[data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgLuM.png)

The label distribution is 21883, 31564 and 48498

The model I have built;

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(250, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], 
train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=20, batch_size=128, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=True)
```

The summary of the model is below;

[model summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftGmk.png)

The first 10 epoch details;

[epoch details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsVJz.png)

And the plot of the result;
[accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGIDz.png)

Other plots for the batch size 32 & 64;[batch size 32 & 64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRPVC.png)

Accuracy changes dramatically for each epoch, does not look like having an increasing trend. I am not sure if the model is ok or it needs to be modified.

Comment: how is your input ?  and do you have unbalanced daaset?

Comment: I've added the structure of the input and the number of the labels

Comment: what batch size you using, have you tested it with diff batchsize, and layers. and its not changing much, as in graph also, you can see that y-axis shows accuracy from 82 to 88 , and if you scale it on 0 to 1 graph, it will look smooth

Comment: the original plot was 128, I've also added plots for the batch sizes 32 & 64

Comment: Since the network is not even getting close to an accuracy of 1.0 on the training data, I'd suggest adding one or more LSTM layers (searching for some configuration which will yield acceptable results). And if you find the test accuracy to be too low after all, I'd look into how to prevent overfitting from happening. Maybe adjusting the learning rate (e.g.trying slower training or testing variable learning rate), increasing dropout etc. But not getting exactly the same error/accuracy on train and test data is not unusual, in general. In practice, performance on test tends to be slightly worse.